# Joomla 2.5 Add Option Groups to Article

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm playing with Joomla 2.5.9 (The latest 2.X download). Do you know how you can **add additional menu's** to the "Article Manager: Edit Article" page? (This is in the **Administration**)

Their API gives me some hint on several things but I am don't know what this right "Slide Down Option Area" is called in the Administration.

In the right area there are things such as:

- Publishing options
- Article Options
- Configure Edit Screen
- Images and Links

etc..

I want to know where to start to add my own, or where they are already built in the system so I can base mine off it -- Is this a plugin,  module, or something else? :)

Comment: It looks like the path to the template is here: `administrator\components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\edit.php` -- But this doesn't seem to have any "hooks" that I can see yet.

Comment: Im starting to wonder if this is possible without rigging the default installation

Comment: I would like to suggest not to change the core files of it.You can make your own plugin to add such functionality in it.

Comment: Thank you that is what I want to do, but do you know what API documents I should be looking at? What the name of that right menu might by in a API docs? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i say don't change any of the core file in Joomla. If you want to add any functionality into the article manager you can make your own plugin to add functionality in it. For doing this see this link :

[Creating a content plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_content_plugin)

I hope this is what you looking for.Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are some extensions that allow you to do that.

I recommend (although somewhat buggy and a code mess) this one:

[FieldsAttach](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/18564)

It does exactly what you want.

Or, you could make your own as Toretto suggests, there are some tutorials on creating a plugin for extra items in the article form, but the already-made-extension route seems to make more sence.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using FieldsAttach for this sort of thing, for a few years, the code is often a little messy, that is true, but the the concepts are clean and eloquent. Brian Teeman explains it well from an integrator point of view in his talk at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2WLKWbRj5U but in some ways it is even more compelling from a developer's perspective.

However, after watching Marco Ding's Joomla Day UK 2016 talk on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDh1IPuZAVA I think DPFields may be a better choice.  The architecture is perhaps more rugged and neater, but also because it may well end up being a core extension in Joomla in the near future. More info on DPFields is at http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/dpfields , https://joomla.digital-peak.com/products/dpfields and https://joomla.digital-peak.com/documentation/162-dpfields .